# How to Copy data from s3 to Redshift with "," in the field values

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am faced with "Extra column(s) found" error while reading the data from S3 to Redshift.
Since my data has 863830 rows an 21 columns, ill give you a small example of how the data is.

```
create table test_table(
name varchar(500),
age varchar(500)
)
```

and my data would be

```
(ABC,12)
(First,Last,25)
```

where First,last should go into a single columns

Unfortunately, i am unable to do that with this copy command

```
COPY test_table from 'path'
iam_role 'credentials'
region 'us-east-1'
IGNOREHEADER 1
delimiter as ','
```

Is there any way to accomodate commas into a field ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it a CSV file that you're trying to load? If so, try loading with CSV format parameter specified in the command, rather than using delimiter ',' parameter. Here's an example -

`COPY test_table from 'path'
iam_role 'credentials'
region 'us-east-1'
IGNOREHEADER 1
CSV;`

If that doesn't help, you may have to use the ESCAPE parameter. This would need modifications in your file too. Here's an example - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html#r_COPY_command_examples-copy-data-with-the-escape-option

Comment: adding ```CSV``` to the end of the command worked for me. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your data doesn't conform to the CSV specification.  See [RTF-4180](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt)

To store your example data the field with the comma in it needs to be enclosed in " "

```
ABC,12
"First,Last",25
```

The parentheses in the data file will also need to be removed as these will be interpreted as part of the data fields.

Alternatively you could change the delimiter of your data from "," to something else like "%".  However if this character is in your data then you are right back where you started.  Ad hoc delimited files only work if you use a character that will never be in your data.  This is why I recommend that you use the more robust CSV specification and use the "CSV" option to COPY.